# size option in find(version 4.4.2) does not understand kilo prefix

Tags: find

For some reason, `find` does not seem to accept kilobytes prefix:

```
T42 ~ # find /root/ /home/noc/ \( -type f -size -1k \) -exec grep -iH hangup {} \;
find: `/home/noc/.gvfs': Permission denied
T42 ~ # find /root/ /home/noc/ \( -type f -size -1000 \) -exec grep -iH hangup {} \;
/root/minicom.log:20130524 17:31:22 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20130528 14:49:39 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20130806 09:55:39 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20130806 09:55:43 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20130918 13:58:38 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20130918 13:58:38 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131017 10:36:24 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131017 12:44:28 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131017 12:49:00 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131017 12:49:00 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131017 17:11:45 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131017 17:11:45 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131114 18:16:26 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131216 12:36:34 Hangup (0:00:00)
/root/minicom.log:20131217 12:27:52 Hangup (0:00:00)
find: `/home/noc/.gvfs': Permission denied
/home/noc/gnupg/gnupg-2.0.20/g10/cpr.c:            raise (SIGINT);  /* nothing to hangup under DOS */
^C
T42 ~ #
```

Am I doing something wrong or how should one use *size* suffixes in `find`?

Comment: Please note that 1000 and 1k are not the same.

Comment: @Manuel Gutierrez Thanks! I missed that `-size n` without a prefix defaults to 512 byte blocks. This means that `-size -1000` is actually from 0B to 511488B(included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without suffix it's using 512-byte blocks (b). 1k and 1024c would be the same regarding their units.

But keep in mind that it's searching for the "used n units of space". To store 1 byte you need one 1-byte block or one 1k block or one 1M block ...

- -size -1k would find only 0k (=0 byte) files
- -size 1k would find >0 bytes <=1024 bytes
- -size -2k would find files <=1024 bytes but not >=1025 bytes

Comment: thanks for explaining this! So `-size -3k` is from 0 to <= 2048 bytes? And `-size -11M` would find files in size <=10485760? So basically `-size n[prefix]` will match files which are <="n-1B*[prefix]"(for example "3*1024-1*1024") and `+size n[prefix]` will match files which are >="n+1B*[prefix]"(for example "11*2^10+1*2^10")?